# StaleElementReferenceException in for loop with Python & Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, exception

I am trying to scrape newspaper articles from Le Monde's website, and have written a small simple script to do so. It has worked quite well so far but for some obscure reason, its recent runs have all brought me to a `StaleElementReferenceException` error, without me being exactly able to pinpoint why.

This is my code:

```
for i in urls[1797:4383]:
    browser.get(i)
    try: 
        pages_section = browser.find_element(by='css selector', value='section[class="river__pagination"]')
        tmp_pages = pages_section.find_elements(by='css selector', value='a')
        nb_pages = len(tmp_pages) #this is the number of page for each date
    except NoSuchElementException:
        nb_pages = 0
    
    #for each page
    for n in range(2, nb_pages+2): #+1 is because range does not include the last element / until excludes
        #collecting everything
        titles = titles = browser.find_elements(by = "css selector", value = "h3[class='teaser__title']")
        subtitles = browser.find_elements(by = "css selector", value = "p[class='teaser__desc']")
        dates = browser.find_elements(by = "css selector", value = "span[class='meta__date']")
     
#these two loops seem to be the problematic ones – i think?    
        #writing them into a df
        for i in range(len(titles)):
                articles = {}
                articles["title"] = titles[i].text
                articles["subtitle"] = subtitles[i].text
                articles["date"] = dates[i].text
                all_articles.append(articles)
                        
        #click on the next page
        sleep(1.3)
        if n <= nb_pages:
                browser.find_element(by='link text', value=str(n)).click()
            
    sleep(1)

all_articles = pd.DataFrame(all_articles)
all_articles.to_excel("/Users/victor/Desktop/test.xlsx", index=False)
```

I think I understand what `StaleElementReferenceException` means, but I don't really understand how it is a problem in my case, and especially not why it is a problem only once in a while.

The error message I last got is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 18, in <module>
  File "/Users/victor/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 84, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "/Users/victor/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 396, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/victor/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/victor/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.110)
```

Would anyone be able to point me towards my eventual mistake and help me fix it? Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I ran VSCode's debugger and it seems that the problematic line is:

```
articles["title"] = titles[i].text
```

I still have trouble understanding *why* however.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I have found a way myself. In case that can help anyone in the same situation in the future, I did this and it seems to be working just fine now.

```
for n in range(2, nb_pages+2): #+1 is because range does not include the last element / until excludes
        #collecting everything
        titles = browser.find_elements(by = "css selector", value = "h3[class='teaser__title']")
        subtitles = browser.find_elements(by = "css selector", value = "p[class='teaser__desc']")
        dates = browser.find_elements(by = "css selector", value = "span[class='meta__date']")
        
        #writing them into a df
        try:
            for i in range(len(titles)):
                articles = {}
                articles["title"] = titles[i].text
                articles["subtitle"] = subtitles[i].text
                articles["date"] = dates[i].text
                all_articles2.append(articles)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            titles = browser.find_elements(by = "css selector", value = "h3[class='teaser__title']")
            subtitles = browser.find_elements(by = "css selector", value = "p[class='teaser__desc']")
            dates = browser.find_elements(by = "css selector", value = "span[class='meta__date']")
            for i in range(len(titles)):
                articles = {}
                articles["title"] = titles[i].text
                articles["subtitle"] = subtitles[i].text
                articles["date"] = dates[i].text
                all_articles2.append(articles)
```